# How do I pass some value from one view controller to UINavigationController in swift 4 without using segue?

Tags: ios, swift3, swift4, xcode9

I want to pass value from one UIviewController to UINavigationViewController without using segue in swift 4.

My sample code is following

```
let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MainMenuId") as! UINavigationViewController
vc.sendValue = String    //String send to sendValue which present in UINavigationController           
self.present(vc!, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

But when I try to send at at that time my app is crashed and get error

**Could not cast value of type 'UINavigationController'  to 'UIViewController'**

So How do I pass value from above structure without using segue. Thx in advance ;)

Comment: Why are u passing data to `UINavigationViewController` `UINavigationViewController` does not have a property named `sendValue` finally why are u assigning `vc.sendValue` to a DataType `String` I dont think the above code would even compile

Comment: @SandeepBhandari:  sendValue is not a property its string variable which declare in UINavigationController. I want to pass username which called in my UIviewController and show it into my next UINavigationViewController.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code:

```
let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:"MainMenuId") as! UIViewController
let nav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)

vc.sendValue = String              
self.present(nav!, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Sorry but it did not work. when I used.                                                    let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:"MainMenuId") as! UIViewController       It gave me error: sendValue does not present in UIViewController :(

Comment: use your controller name instead UIViewController.

Comment: Yes I used but it gives same above error  :(  How do I get rootViewController? I used UIViewController as name of my controller and UINavigationController as name of my navigation controller bt not work